# Nueva ventana en onclick de JavaScript

Tags: botón

tengo un boton HTML con funcion Java

(button onclick="document.location='https://www.w3schools.com/'">Tutorial</button)

Pero quiero que me abra en una nueva ventana! Que me hace falta?

Comment: te hace falta buscar en google ;) y tambien ponerle un target...

Comment: gbianchi <button onclick="document.location='https://www.w3schools.com/'" target="_blank">Tutorial</button>???? Porque hace exactamente lo mismo que sin el target, ó lo estoy poniendo mal??